# Anacron doesn't appear to run anything on Debian, but why?

Tags: debian, cron, anacron

I have an odd problem with my Debian server.  Up until a few weeks ago, anacron was running my cron jobs fine and I can see I have backups from then so it was running stuff.  Then it appears to have just stopped running cron tasks in /etc/cron.daily/weekly/monthly.  The logs, however, don't show any issues.  Here's my recent anacron log:

```
Nov 27 22:30:58 localhost anacron[2229443]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-11-27
Nov 27 22:30:58 localhost anacron[2229443]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Nov 27 22:30:58 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 27 23:33:19 localhost systemd[1]: Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
Nov 27 23:33:19 localhost anacron[2230690]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-11-27
Nov 27 23:33:19 localhost anacron[2230690]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Nov 27 23:33:19 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 28 07:34:01 localhost systemd[1]: Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
Nov 28 07:34:01 localhost anacron[2240027]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-11-28
Nov 28 07:34:01 localhost anacron[2240027]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Nov 28 07:34:01 localhost anacron[2240027]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Nov 28 07:39:01 localhost anacron[2240027]: Job `cron.daily' started
Nov 28 07:39:02 localhost anacron[2240113]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2023-11-28
Nov 28 07:39:03 localhost anacron[2240027]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Nov 28 07:39:03 localhost anacron[2240027]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Nov 28 07:39:03 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Killing process 2240176 (ConfigServer Ve) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 28 07:39:03 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Killing process 2240182 (sleep) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 28 07:39:03 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 28 08:30:42 localhost systemd[1]: Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
Nov 28 08:30:42 localhost anacron[2241219]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-11-28
Nov 28 08:30:42 localhost anacron[2241219]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

It seems to claim that the `cron.daily` (as well as weekly/monthly, further back) are running fine and exiting normally.  But no backups are being made, and no emails are being sent to me (I setup a test script that should always print output and therefore generate an email).  I can't for the life of my figure out why anacron apparently isn't doing anything, and isn't logging any errors.

I don't *remember* doing anything back a few weeks ago that could've caused this.  Here's my /etc/anacrontab:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

What can I do to debug this and figure out what's wrong?  My OS is Debian 12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just discovered (thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/a/719493/16153)) that `run-parts` ignores files/links that have an extension; it doesn't match the `.` character.  No idea why.  Changed my symlinks in `/etc/cron.daily` not to have the `.extension` and now they run.  Crazy.

Comment: What would happen for example when a package-provided entry is locally changed by the administrator and gets upgraded to a different content, leaving a .dpkg-old or .dpkg-new, or with an editor leaving a ~ or .bak file around? I wouldn't want the crontab entry to be executed twice because of this.

Comment: Seems to me that those files shouldn't be left in cron.daily